# How to make a json string by reading file line by line?

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
machineA=1.2.3.4.5
machineB=2.5.7.8.9
```

I need to read above file and make a string like this for each line:

```
{"test":"hello world.","server":"machineA","ip":"1.2.3.4.5","reason":"data"}
{"test":"hello world.","server":"machineB","ip":"2.5.7.8.9","reason":"data"}
```

As you can see in my above json string only value of `server` and `ip` is changing and other remaining two keys, it's value stays same always. How can I generate a string like this for each line?

I am not able to figure out how to make correspoding json for each line and print them out on the console.

```
f = open('hosts.txt')
line = f.readline()
while line:
    print(line)
    machine=line.split("=")[0]
    ip=line.split("=")[1]

    # now how to make a json string for each line
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to use the JSON library just because the output format is JSON. Try one of these:

```
output_line = '{"test":"hello world.","server":"%s","ip":"%s","reason":"data"}'%(
    machine, ip)
output_line = '{{"test":"hello world.","server":"{}","ip":"{}","reason":"data"}'.format(
    machine, ip)
output_line = f'{{"test":"hello world.","server":"{machine}","ip":"{ip}","reason":"data"}'
```

Note that the final line only works on recent versions of Python3.

Comment: Sure, provided the machine names don't have quotes or escapes in them; otherwise, using the `json` library will see you right every time. It's also *part of the standard library*, so it's not as if it isn't easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest making a dictionary then using the built in `json` module to convert it to a JSON string, because I find that cleaner to read.

```
import json

mydict = {
    "test": "hello world.",
    "server": machine,
    "ip": ip,
    "reason": "data"
 }
 json.dumps(mydict)
```

See [Robᵩ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50518327/5369466) for how to do it without the `json` module